# How to pass region to the SKLearnProcessor - botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using the following code to do a sklearn transformation job in sagemaker:

```
region = boto3.session.Session().region_name
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
    framework_version="1.0-1", role=role,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge", instance_count=1,
    # sagemaker_session = Session()
)
out_path = os.path.join(bucket, prefix, f'test_transform/data.csv')
sklearn_processor.run(
    code="preprocess.py",
    inputs = [
        ProcessingInput(source = 'my_package/', destination = '/opt/ml/processing/input/code/my_package/')
    ],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="test_transform_data", 
                         source = '/opt/ml/processing/output/test_transform',
                         destination = out_path),
    ],
    arguments=["--time-slot-minutes", "30min"]
)
```

Within the above code, it's running preprocess.py, and (within) preprocess.py loads the data from snowflake database using the credentials saved in aws secretsmanager:

```
region = boto3.Session().region_name
secrets_client = boto3.client(service_name='secretsmanager', region_name=region)
```

So here's where error happen: first line above returns region as None, so the the second line of code raises `botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region`

In this case, how can I pass the region to SKLearnProcessor or is there any other way to make the code working within the processing job instance?

FYI:
the source of input `'my_package/'` is in the structure below to install packages and include py dependencies used in `preprocess.py`

```
├── my_package
│   ├── file1.py
│   ├── file2.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── preprocess.py
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set following in the code preprocess.py solved the issue:

```
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'us-west-2'
```

Comment: Agree with this solution, but would suggest a small change to improve it: In my experience the problem is that SM Processing sets `AWS_REGION` but not `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` - so you can actually avoid hard-coding regions in your Processing scripts by simply doing: `os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = os.environ['AWS_REGION']`

Answer (score 0):

The two easiest ways are to to either set it in your ~/.aws/config

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
```

or you can use an environment variable as in:

`export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2`

but you do need to tell boto3 which region to use.

Check out the documentation about how to input variables to boto3:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html

Comment: Hey @Will , I'm running above codes in a sagemaker notebook instance, and then it creates an Sagemaker processing job to run preprocess.py in another instance where this issue happen, so I need to setup the ~/.aws/config in that data processing job instance (not my sagemaker notebook local) created by running the code, do you know how to set it up?

Comment: It looks like you can customize environment variables so you could set AWS_DEFAULT_REGION https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_ProcessingJob.html